# GridView images drag and drop flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I have a code using Flutter framework which allows to select multiple images and view the images before uploading to firebase.
After selecting images, I would like to have the possibility to drag and drop these images in order to reorder these images and save them later with the order chooses by the user.

I tried to implement this drag and drop but all the examples I saw are for ListView, which is not the case in my situation :(

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:drag_and_drop_gridview/devdrag.dart';
import 'package:drag_and_drop_gridview/drag.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:image_cropper/image_cropper.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart' as firebase_storage;
import 'package:path/path.dart' as Path;

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';


class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {


  bool uploading = false;
  double val = 0;
  CollectionReference imgRef;
  firebase_storage.Reference ref;

  List<File> _image = [];
  final picker = ImagePicker();
  
  int variableSet = 0, variableSetHeader = 0;
  ScrollController _scrollController;
  double width;
  double height;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Horizontal DragAndDropGridView'),
          actions: [
            // ignore: deprecated_member_use
            FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    uploading = true;
                  });
                  uploadFile().whenComplete(() => Navigator.of(context).pop());
                },

                child: Text(
                  'upload',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                )),
          ],

        ),




        body: Stack(
          children: [
          Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
             child: DragAndDropGridView.horizontal(
              controller: _scrollController,
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 5,
                childAspectRatio: 3 / 4.5,
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                child: GridView.builder(
                    itemCount: _image.length + 1,
                    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        crossAxisCount: 3),
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return index == 0
                          ? Center(
                        child: IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                            onPressed: () =>
                            !uploading ? chooseImage() : null),
                      )
                          : Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(3),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            image: DecorationImage(
                              image: FileImage(_image[index - 1]),
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            )
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                ),
              ),
              itemCount: _image.length,
              onWillAccept: (oldIndex, newIndex) => true,
              onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex) {
                int indexOfFirstItem = _image.indexOf(_image[oldIndex]);
                int indexOfSecondItem = _image.indexOf(_image[newIndex]);

                if (indexOfFirstItem > indexOfSecondItem) {
                  for (int i = _image.indexOf(_image[oldIndex]);
                  i > _image.indexOf(_image[newIndex]);
                  i--) {
                    var tmp = _image[i - 1];
                    _image[i - 1] = _image[i];
                    _image[i] = tmp;
                  }
                } else {
                  for (int i = _image.indexOf(_image[oldIndex]);
                  i < _image.indexOf(_image[newIndex]);
                  i++) {
                    var tmp = _image[i + 1];
                    _image[i + 1] = _image[i];
                    _image[i] = tmp;
                  }
                }
                setState(() {});
              },
            ),
          ),


            uploading
                ? Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      child: Text(
                        'uploading...',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),

                    CircularProgressIndicator(
                      value: val,
                      valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.green),
                    ),

                  ],
                )
            )
                : Container(),
          ],
        )
    );
  }


  chooseImage() async {
    final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    setState(() {
      _image.add(File(pickedFile?.path));
    });
    if (pickedFile.path == null) retrieveLostData();
  }

  Future<void> retrieveLostData() async {
    final LostData response = await picker.getLostData();
    if (response.isEmpty) {
      return;
    }
    if (response.file != null) {
      setState(() {
        _image.add(File(response.file.path));
      });
    } else {
      print(response.file);
    }
  }

  Future uploadFile() async {
    int i = 1;
    var firebaseUser =  FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.email;
    for (var img in _image) {
      setState(() {
        val = i / _image.length;
      });
      ref = firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
          .ref()
          .child('${firebaseUser}/Livres/${Path.basename(img.path)}');
      await ref.putFile(img).whenComplete(() async {
        await ref.getDownloadURL().then((value) {
          imgRef.add({'url': value});
          i++;
        });
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    var firebaseUser =  FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.email;

    super.initState();
    imgRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(firebaseUser);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use reorderable_grid_view package. It is null-safe & easy to use.

[reorderable_grid_view](https://pub.dev/packages/reorderable_grid_view)

Its ReorderableGridView.count method has same properties as of GridView.count with some extra properties like reorder to drag-n-drop/reorder the gridview.

Below youtube video will help you to get more details on gridview drag & drop.

[Flutter - Drag & drop items in Gridview](https://youtu.be/SThz54hQZQ0)

Answer (score 0):

Use Draggable widget or use this plugin [draggable gridView](https://pub.dev/packages/drag_and_drop_gridview)

Comment: I tried it too. even if I dont have any error in the code, its not working. maybe its due to what I have in addition to images. I updated my code using draggable widget

Comment: Did you use key property of children and did you update UI after dragging?

Comment: unfortunately no, i just checked the use of 'key properties' and indeed it seems that this can solve the problem. but as I never used it I dont know how to place it in the code above :(

Comment: Key is used to identify widget from others, so Key("parameter") parameter should be different from other key 's parameter

Comment: Is there a null-safe alternative to this?